# Вывод количества букв в строке

Tags: c++, c

Можно ли при помощи printf подсчитать количество букв в строке? если можно то каким способом или можно это сделать по другому?

Comment: `strlen` не подойдет?

Comment: Если вывести строку через `printf`, то результат `printf` - это количество выведенных символов, т.е. ваше "количество букв". Вы об этом спрашиваете?

Answer (score 3):

Делаем *man 3 printf* и читаем:

> ВОЗВРАЩАЕМОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
>          При успешном выполнении данные функции возвращают количество напечатанных символов  (не  включая байт null, используемый в конце
>   выводимых строк).